# Set UITableViewHeaderFooterView margin values (on scrolling)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I build a `UITableView` with section header that can expand a specific section. I am using a custom view from a .xib file for a `UITableViewHeaderView`. I want to set margin values of the `HeaderView` so that it is not full width and stays on top when scrolling down (not full height).

1. As you can see in the animation the view has full width - is it possible to add a margin to the header that there is some space between the `HeaderView` and the edge of the screen.
2. I want to reduce the height of the sticky header if the `UITableView` is scrolled - so that there is just the text of the button visible on top of the screen. I have implemented the following delegate command from `UIScrollView` which works fine, but it reduces the margin for the first `HeaderView` so that it moves behind the navigation bar (see in animation) - how can I avoid that?

   ```
   -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
   {
       CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 20;
       if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
           scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
       } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
           scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
       }
   }
   ```

   [image: Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could put a subview with a margin in your headerview.
2. Setting the height is certainly possible and is done by setting the frame, but you could also make your navigation bar non-translucent, which would save you a ton of coding.

   ```
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
   ```

If you want to change the height, your code would look something like:

```
CGRect frame = header.frame;
frame.size.height = 44;
header.frame = frame;
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:header];
```